# Overloading ClearAll[] to take no arguments

Tags: function-construction, syntax-highlighting

I use the command

> ClearAll["Global`*"]

so much that I thought it would be nice to have a function that called it. Since by default `ClearAll` requires an argument, I decided to overload it and have it so when no arguments are passed to `ClearAll` it clears Global.

> `Unprotect[ClearAll]`
>
> ClearAll[]:=ClearAll["Global`*"];
>
> `Protect[ClearAll]`

However, mathematica still expects an argument to the function, resulting in this

[image]

It still works fine, but is there any way to remove the red arrow? I've tried

`SyntaxInformation[ClearAll] := {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {___}}` which should allow it to accept 0 arguments, but it still complains about it.

Comment: But if you defined `ClearAll[]` in global context, would not then calling  `ClearAll[]` first time clears your own `ClearAll[]` that you just defined? Since `ClearAll` from the system is in the system context `Context[ClearAll]`. I agree with you, it will be nice to have a system command to clear all, without having to specify the context. I always mixes up the * and the ` order

Comment: In general, you might want to define it as `ClearAll[] := ClearAll[$Context <> "*"]`

Comment: @rm-rf @Nasser I actually put my overloaded `ClearAll[]` into a package which is loaded on startup. As part of the `ClearAll[]` definition I reload that package after the clear. That information doesn't really have to do with the question though, so I left it out.

Comment: @Nasser Since `ClearAll` is in the ``System` `` context any definitions you attach to it will also be in the ``System` `` context.

Comment: @rm-rf "`ClearAll::ssym: $Context<>* is not a symbol or a string. >>`" -- you probably want `ClearAll @@ {$Context <> "*"}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't get that error, but I agree that an evaluate should be thrown in. A simpler way: ``ClearAll@"`*"``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 10 under Windows I am unable to reproduce the problem you describe:

```
Unprotect[ClearAll];

ClearAll[] := ClearAll["Global`*"]

SyntaxInformation[ClearAll] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {___}};

Protect[ClearAll]
```

In the Notebook:

[image]

Without the definition above:

[image]

Comment: OP might have issued the `SyntaxInformation..` command after doing the `Protect` like you did?

Comment: @Nasser No, I put it after Unprotect

Comment: corrected what I meant above. I typed it wrong.

Comment: It seems that typing all commands directly into the notebook works, but putting it into a `.m` file loaded at startup causes it to not work...

Comment: @user2612743 That actually makes some sense, as something later in the loading process may be resetting `SyntaxInformation[ClearAll]`.  Have you confirmed that it is as you set it after *Mathematica* is up and running?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, it only starts working fine from the `.m` file after I issue ClearAll[] once.